# Am I able to add eclipse-plugin to an Xtext project after it has been created?

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have two problems, possible because of the same reason.

***1.Existing project cant launch eclipse plugin:***

I imported a gradle xtext project, generated the Xtext artifacts and it works fine from the code. However when I am right click on the project there is no option for "run as ... eclipse application". Inside the run configuration I can find it and launch it but the grammar syntax rules arent in effect, no highlightning ,no underscoring ...nothing(I got neither errors nor warn).

Where should I begin to debug this problem?

***2.Starting project from scratch:***

I followed the tutorial on Xtext documentation site (https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html).
It works fine with the eclipse plugin.
However when I start a new xtext project and uncheck the "Eclipse Plugin" in the Advanced Xtext Configuration section during the project creation, the eclipse plugin wont be created(and this is the expected in this case).

Am I able to fix it **AFTER** the project is created?

Thanks!

Comment: in the wizard you can select gradle and eclipse. what exactly is not working with that?

Comment: ^^ As you can see from the second part , I know how to start it correctly. But when I start it through the wizard **without** "eclipse plugin" checked, then afterward it wont work of course and I am curious how can I add it to the project?

Comment: use the wizard, compare the files and exchange the different ones e.g. .project and .classpath files, manifests build.properties etc

Comment: ok thanks, that would work for the second case.
How would you start debugging in the first case?

Comment: what do you mean by debugging? if you use gradle you target a standalone app (or a language server) so you can use unit tests or start the language server in debug mode

Comment: I mean debugging why the launched runtime eclipse doesnt contain syntax check. The code itself (tests, dsl language parser) work fine.

Comment: if you dont have eclipse plugins it makes no sense. if you want to have eclipse plugins you need to have eclipse plugins for everything => 2